# Angular Bootstrap Datetimepicker not reflected in variable

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

my project is here and should be run in firefox

https://github.com/samanthalvarner/AHDCEquip/tree/master/AHDCEquip

The issue is when a date is picked from the date time picker it is not reflected in the angular variable on the page.  In the view fillOrders.html `<input data-ng-model="dateOfCal" type='text' class="form-control" />` selected at the top of the page should be reflected at the bottom of the page

Date of Calibration:

#### {{dateOfCal}}

When a date is selected from the picker, it does not reflect the date in the angular variable.

Comment: Are you using ui-bootstrap datepicker

Comment: I recommend ditching bootstrap-datetimepicker in favor of the one in ui-bootstrap for a pure angular approach.  The one you've chosen requires jquery manipulation of the DOM and subsequently handling of the data,  The one in ui-bootstrap is an angular plugin that already handles the data through ng-model.

Comment: Yeah even I saw the code you should go for ui-bootstrap date-picker

Comment: I will look into that, thanks

Comment: @PankajKumar - I have started to implement ui-bootstrap, but when I include ui-bootstrap as a module in the app declaration, it immediately causes issues.  what do I need to do in addition to var app = angular.module('AHDCEquip', ['ngRoute', 'ui-bootstrap']); to begin using the directive?  Here is the new version https://github.com/samanthalvarner/AHDCEquip/tree/ui-bootstrap-version/AHDCEquip/AHDCEquip

Comment: I needed to add javascript to my controller from the page where examples of the directive are